# Linq join on multiple tables with null values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to perform a request from my database build as this

```
Table Zipcodes
string Zipcode
string Description
string StateCode
string RegionCode
string CountryCode

Table States
string StateCode
string StateName

Table Region
string RegionCode
string RegionName

Table Country
string CountryCode
string CountryName
```

So, i want to list all my Zipcodes with names instead of codes.

My ZIPcode table contains 8 lines.
in ZIPCode table, only states codes can be Null.

Here is my request :

```
var dset = from s in db.ZIPCODEs
join u in db.COUNTRies on s.COUNTRYCODE equals u.COUNTRYCODE
join v in db.STATES on s.STATECODE equas v.STATECODE 
join w in db.REGIONS on s.REGIONCODE equals w.REGIONCODE                     
select new ZIPCODEListViewModel
    {
    ID = s.ID,
    ZIPCODE1 = s.ZIPCODE1,
    DESCRIPTION = s.DESCRIPTION,
    STATECODE = s.STATECODE,
    CONTRYCODE = s.COUNTRYCODE,
    REGIONCODE = s.REGIONCODE,
    STATECODE = s.STATENAME,
    COUNTRYNAME =u.DESCRIPTION,
    STATENAME = v.DESCRIPTION,
    REGIONNAME = w.DESCRIPTION
   };
```

This returns 0 lines.

If i use join only on COUNTRY and REGION, that contains no null values, I receive all the lines.

My question is : How can i build my request to return all the lines, and emply string or null in the Statename is Statecode is null ?

Thanks for your help and sorry for bad english && bad linq competences.

Robbie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks a lot.

It helps me to find the solution.

```
var dset = from s in db.ZIPCODEs
           join u in db.COUNTRies on s.COUNTRYCODE equals u.COUNTRYCODE into ulist from u in ulist.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join w in db.REGIONS on s.REGIONCODE equals w.REGIONCODE into wlist from w in wlist.DefaultIfEmpty()      
           join v in db.STATES on s.STATECODE equals v.STATECODE into vlist from v in vlist.DefaultIfEmpty()                          
           select new ZIPCODEListViewModel
          {
            ID = s.ID,
            ZIPCODE1 = s.ZIPCODE1,
            DESCRIPTION = s.DESCRIPTION,
            STATECODE = s.STATECODE,
            COUNTRYCODE = s.COUNTRYCODE,
            REGIONCODE = s.REGIONCODE,
            COUNTRYNAME =u.DESCRIPTION,
            STATENAME = v.DESCRIPTION,
            REGIONNAME = w.DESCRIPTION
        };
```

Return all my lines with blank in fields that cannot be solved by join.

Robbie

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Group Join instead of Join. Group Join work same as Left Join in SQL. Try following Query:

```
var dset = from s in db.ZIPCODEs
           join u in db.COUNTRies on s.COUNTRYCODE equals u.COUNTRYCODE
           Group Join v In db.STATES On s.STATECODE equas v.STATECODE
               Into vlist = Group
               From v In vlist.DefaultIfEmpty() 
           join w in db.REGIONS on s.REGIONCODE equals w.REGIONCODE                     
           select new ZIPCODEListViewModel
          {
            ID = s.ID,
            ZIPCODE1 = s.ZIPCODE1,
            DESCRIPTION = s.DESCRIPTION,
            STATECODE = s.STATECODE,
            CONTRYCODE = s.COUNTRYCODE,
            REGIONCODE = s.REGIONCODE,
            STATECODE = s.STATENAME,
            COUNTRYNAME =u.DESCRIPTION,
            STATENAME = v.DESCRIPTION,
            REGIONNAME = w.DESCRIPTION
        };
```

Comment: Group Join syntax don't works in my C# compiler. But it helps me to find the solution. Thanks !

Comment: Wecome dear. am VB programmer so group join working well in vb side.